# FileSystemWatcher updating textbox on form

Tags: vb.net, onchange, shared, filesystemwatcher

Hey all i am using the **FileSystemWatcher** to check to see if an .ini file has been changed. If it has then i would like for me to be able to update a textbox on my form. Problem being is that its a shared function in order for the **FileSystemWatcher** to work so anything on the form cant be access inside that shared function it seems?

My code:

```
Private Sub frmCamera_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim watcher As New FileSystemWatcher()

    watcher.Path = Application.StartupPath
    watcher.NotifyFilter = (NotifyFilters.LastAccess Or NotifyFilters.LastWrite Or NotifyFilters.FileName Or NotifyFilters.DirectoryName)
    watcher.Filter = "*.ini"
    watcher.SynchronizingObject = Me

    AddHandler watcher.Changed, AddressOf OnChanged
    watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = True
End Sub

Private Shared Sub OnChanged(source As Object, e As FileSystemEventArgs)
    Dim sb1 As New StringBuilder(500)
    Dim theButtonsName As String = ""

    GetPrivateProfileString("camera", "val1", "", sb1, sb1.Capacity, Application.StartupPath & "\savedData.ini")

    main.GetPrivateProfileString("camera", "val1", "", sb1, sb1.Capacity, Application.StartupPath & "\savedData.ini")

    Dim frm As frmCamera = DirectCast(DirectCast(source, FileSystemWatcher).SynchronizingObject, frmCamera)
    frm.TextBox1.Text = "debug: " & sb1.ToString
End Sub
```

I am calling the form above by the main form like so:

```
Public Sub doStuff(ByVal what2Do As String)
   If Trim(lanSent(0)) = "camera" And Trim(lanSent(1)) = "show" Then
      theCam = New Threading.Thread(AddressOf ShowCam)

      theCam.SetApartmentState(Threading.ApartmentState.STA)
      theCam.Start()
   Else
     .....
   End If
End Sub

Private Shared Sub ShowCam()
    Dim ShowCam As New frmCamera
    ShowCam.ShowDialog()
End Sub
```

What i am trying to accomplish is to run some other stuff once it sees that textbox has input in it (TextBox1_TextChanged).

Any help would be great to solve this problem of mine! Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if this will work for you since I do not know why you are using a Shared EventHandler, but you can try using the[`FileSystemWatcher.SynchronizingObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.synchronizingobject%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) Property if you set this to your Form you can retrieve it in your shared method.

```
Private Shared Sub OnChanged(source As Object, e As FileSystemEventArgs)
    Dim sb1 As New StringBuilder(500)
    Dim theButtonsName As String = ""
    GetPrivateProfileString("camera", "val1", "", sb1, sb1.Capacity, Application.StartupPath & "\savedData.ini")

    Dim frm As Form1 = DirectCast(DirectCast(source, FileSystemWatcher).SynchronizingObject, Form1)
    frm.TextBox1.Text = sb1.ToString
 End Sub
```

Intialization of the FileSystemWatcher

```
 Dim watcher As New FileSystemWatcher
 watcher.Path = Application.StartupPath
 watcher.SynchronizingObject = Me  'Assigning your Forms Instance to the SychronizingObject
 watcher.NotifyFilter = (NotifyFilters.LastAccess Or NotifyFilters.LastWrite Or NotifyFilters.FileName Or NotifyFilters.DirectoryName)
 watcher.Filter = "*.ini"
 AddHandler watcher.Changed, AddressOf OnChanged
 watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = True
```

Comment: Does this work even though that code of mine is on the same form? Seemd your code is making another instance of a form and then populating the textbox on that form?

Comment: Yes it does. No it is not making another instance of the form it is just creating a variable and casting the synchronizingObject to your Form. It is the same Instance. Just make sure you assign your form to the SynchronizingObject Property of the FileSystemWatcher. I am just using the SynchronizingObject as a place to store a reference to your Form

Comment: **'sender' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.**

Comment: You are calling it source just change it to that. I just modified the signature of my OnChanged EventHandler to match yours. Also change Form1 to the name of your Form Class

Comment: Check my updated answer above with the code showing you how i call the form in the first place and how i am using your code.

Comment: where is MainTabletMenu_Load located?

Comment: MainTabletMenuLoad is the form i am calling from the main form (the one my program first starts out with) in the **doStuff** function.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46647/discussion-between-mark-hall-and-stealthrt)